# C++ Segmentation Fault when Assigning Class Member Variable

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have a function "testfunc()" within a class "Test" under a namespace "TEST_NS".

In the main program, I've created a pointer to "Test" and would like to point to the "testfunc()" function. No problem...

I declare a private variable "foo" as a member of "Test", and the "testfunc()" function attempts to change the variable. This results in a segmentation fault.

Why does this happen?

---

I've created a simple example to show my issue. The segfault happens when I set `foo = 1;` in test.cpp

Here are the files:

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"

using namespace std;

int main () {
  TEST_NS::Test * test;
  test->testfunc();
  return 0;
}
```

**test.h:**

```
#include <iostream>

namespace TEST_NS
{
  class Test
  {

  int foo;

  public:
    Test();
    ~Test();

    void testfunc();
  };
}
```

**test.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"

using namespace TEST_NS;

Test::Test() { }

Test::~Test() { }

void Test::testfunc()
{
  std::cout << "This is testfunc()!" << std::endl;

  foo = 1;

}
```

The code was compiled with

```
g++ main.cpp test.cpp -o test
```

And run with

```
./test
```

Comment: `TEST_NS::Test * test;` does not point to any valid instance of `TEST_NS::Test`.

Comment: But if I take out the variable assignment in test.cpp, this code works fine. Is that because of some other reason?

Comment: @Drew Calling a method from an uninitialized pointer is undefined behavior. Anything can happen. What is likely happening on your implementation is that since your original method didn't access any data, there was no "reason" for it to crash. When you access a member in the modified version, you now need to access memory. Since your pointer is uninitialized, it's likely pointing at memory you do not have access to, causing the crash when you try to access it. But this is just a guess. Undefined behavior is undefined. The first version could start to crash at any time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to instantiate an object of your class; try

```
TEST_NS::Test * test = new TEST_NS::Test();
test->testfunc();
```

Comment: This is actually specifically answering what I asked. My question now is what's the proper way to delete this instance of the object?

Comment: @florgeng I feel that an answer that use owning raw pointers in it's example should also include some indication that `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` are preferred alternatives when possible, for completeness' sake.

Comment: what we (also a group using pointers) usually do is `delete test;` and then setting the pointer to 0 `test = NULL`

Comment: *"a group using pointers"* - I'm still confused what this is supposed to mean. You should use pointers when you need to, not just because you feel like it

Answer (score 5):

Your `main()` function needs to change; the **preferred** way to write it is

```
int main () {
  TEST_NS::Test test;
  test.testfunc();
  return 0;
}
```

If you really want to use a pointer (why?), then you should write:

```
int main () {
  auto test = new TEST_NS::Test();
  test->testfunc();
  delete test;
  return 0;
}
```

notice the addition of `delete test;`.  But this is bad practice as it creates the potential for memory leaks, especially as more code is added (or if `testfunc()` throws an exception).  If you really need to use pointers, it's **much** better to use [`std::unique_ptr<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

```
int main () {
  auto test = std::make_unique<TEST_NS::Test>();
  test->testfunc();
  return 0;
}
```

notice that this also gets rid of the explicit `new` which is generally a good idea, as well as the `delete` that had to be added; plus, it's exception-safe.

There is very little reason for "naked" `new` or `delete` in modern C++.  Note that you can still get a "raw" pointer by using [`get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get), although [dereferencing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator*) would be preferred

```
 void testfunc(TEST_NS::Test& test)
 {
    test.testfunc();
 }
 // ...
 testfunc(*test);
```

Comment: I'm working in a group where pointers are preferred, so I'm trying to format to their style. Can't you just delete the pointer reference and prevent a leak?

Comment: @Drew You can use `delete` where appropriate, yes.

Comment: @Drew The purpose of `unique_ptr` is that you don't have to remember to preform a `delete` yourself. When Dan speaks of a *" potential for memory leaks"* he means that using owning pointers and `delete` gives you the opportunity to forget to call `delete`, causing a memory leak.